# Merging array json using MergeArrayHandling.Merge. How to define index in newtonsoft library

Tags: arrays, merge, json.net, array-merge

Let take 2 arrays
first:

> [  {"name": "a", "innerArray": [{"first": 1, "second": 1}, {"first":
>   2, "second": 2},]},  {"name": "b", "innerArray": [{"first": 1,
>   "second": 1}, {"first": 2, "second": 2},]} ]

second

> [  {"name": "a", "innerArray": [{"first": 1, "second": 11}, {"first":
>   3, "second": 22},]},  {"name": "c", "innerArray": [{"first": 1,
>   "second": 1}, {"first": 2, "second": 2},]} ]

I want to merge them having the output like this

> [   {"name": "a", "innerArray": [{"first": 1, "second": 11}, {"first":
>   2, "second": 2}, {"first": 3, "second": 22}]},   {"name": "b",
>   "innerArray": [{"first": 1, "second": 1}, {"first": 2, "second":
>   2},]}, {"name": "c", "innerArray": [{"first": 1, "second": 1},
>   {"first": 2, "second": 2},]} ]

Is that possible using json.net ?
I know that there is MergeArrayHandling option which can be set to MergeArrayHandling.Merge
which in description is defined as "Merge array items together, matched by index."
However I didn't find any example of it.

Whenever I am trying to merge them the result is simply replacing the old value with new one.

```
JArray o1 = JArray.Parse(@"first array")
JArray o2 = JArray.Parse(@"second array")

o1.Merge(o2, new JsonMergeSettings
{
MergeArrayHandling = MergeArrayHandling.Merge
});

string json = o1.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

The merge option works based on the array index as it says, So for instance if you have an array `[1,2,3]` and `[4]` and choose the `MergeArrayHandling.Merge` Option you will get the result `[4,2,3]` because both share an `index 0` so the value from the incoming is taken over the source. If no index is shared then the source will remain which explains the `2,3` in the result array.

To answer the your specific question *yes and no* the result you want resembles what would be achieved via a `union` or `concat` option, however those don't work because they don't recurse through the objects like `merge` does, The only way to achieve this would be to break down the Json yourself and do separate merges which is a bit more exhaustive but technically doable.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing everything correctly, no need for any custom logic.
As you said what you need to do is to specify an index and this is quite easy:
Let's say you have this:

```
{
   "abc": "123",
   "testArray":
   [
      { "One": 1 },
      { "Two": 2 },
      { "Three" 3 }
   ]
}
```

And you want to update the second element from `{ "Two": 2 }` to `{ "Ten": 10 }` all you have to do is to provide your second array like this:

```
{
   "testArray":
   [
      {  },
      { "Ten": 10 }
   ]
}
```

To conclude: for merge operations you need to provide a full path (that's why there's `testArray` in update request) and specify the array index by adding as many empty `{}` as many indexes you need to skip.

This means that your update json should look like this:

`[{"innerArray":[{"second":11},{},{"first":3,"second":22}]},{},{"name":"c","innerArray":[{"first":1,"second":1},{"first":2,"second":2}]}]`